# plot one of 500 trees in randomForest package

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

How can plot trees in output of `randomForest` function in same names packages in R? For example I use `iris` data and want to plot first tree in 500 output tress. my code is

```
model <-randomForest(Species~.,data=iris,ntree=500)
```

Comment: Does the following answer help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree

Comment: @Avitus thanks for answer, but i can not undrestand. can you get me a simple code for plot first tree in output of randomForest function?

Comment: I add an answer below for the `randomForest` package; other packages-like `party`-allow for similar functionalities

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getTree()` function in the `randomForest` package (official guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf)

On the `iris` dataset:

```
require(randomForest)
data(iris)

## we have a look at the k-th tree in the forest
k <- 10
getTree(randomForest(iris[, -5], iris[, 5], ntree = 10), k, labelVar = TRUE)
```

Comment: how can plot this tree? please add draw plot code to above code. thanks

Comment: @Amin the above code gives you the selected tree (`k <- 10`). If you want to visualize it, you need a bit more effort (I am not aware of any direct plotting function in `randomForest`). Please have a look at this https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/03/16/rf_plot_ggraph

Answer (score 1):

You may use `cforest` to plot like below, I have hardcoded the value to 5, you may change as per your requirement.

```
ntree <- 5
library("party")
cf <- cforest(Species~., data=iris,controls=cforest_control(ntree=ntree))

for(i in 1:ntree){
pt <- prettytree(cf@ensemble[[i]], names(cf@data@get("input"))) 
nt <- new("Random Forest BinaryTree") 
nt@tree <- pt 
nt@data <- cf@data 
nt@responses <- cf@responses 

pdf(file=paste0("filex",i,".pdf"))
plot(nt, type="simple")
dev.off()

}
```

`cforest` is another implementation of random forest, It can't be said which is better but in general there are few differences that we can see. The difference is that `cforest` uses conditional inferences where we put more weight to the terminal nodes in comparison to `randomForest` package where the implementation provides equal weights to terminal nodes.

In general `cofrest` uses weighted mean and `randomForest` uses normal average. You may want to check [**this**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjj5cuL45TUAhXFuI8KHVOFBv0QFggnMAA&url=https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v050i11/v50i11.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFI5QjlDxChlrpgPp-CRygG2vMv-Q&sig2=XtSTnanFFsxYj_QmzfGAEQ&cad=rja) .

Comment: thanks for answer. I want to use `randomForest`, can I use `cforest` instead of `randomForest`?