# How can I plot a tree selected from the random forest created using "caret" package in R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am newbie in R and I need to know how to plot a tree selected from a **random forest** training model created using the **train ()** function in **caret** package.

First and foremost, I used a training dataset to create a fitting model of a random forest using the **train()** function. The created random forest contains about 500 trees. Is there any methodology to create a plot of a selected tree?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CRAN package `party` offers a method called `prettyTree`.
Look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `randomForest` package does not have any built-in functionality to plot individual trees. You can extract trees using the `getTree()` function, but nothing is provided to plot / visualize it. This question may be a duplicate as a quick search yielded approaches other people have used to extract trees from a random forest are found
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree) and [here](https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/03/16/rf_plot_ggraph) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237739/plot-one-of-500-trees-in-randomforest-package)